# Django where is celery task information saved?

Tags: django, save, task, celery

I am wondering where the celery task info. is saved. I checked the tables in the database and find no relevant items. It seems when I shut down the local server and restart it later, celery knows the tasks which are in the queue.

Solution: task info is saved by the broker, redis in my case.
Redis will create a file 'dump.rdb' in the directory where you run manage.py(depends on the redis-config file). The following link can be referred to dump and restore the dump.rdb between different servers. 
http://zdk.blinkenshell.org/redis-backup-and-restore/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In celery, we're using [**`Brokers`**](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html) to store task information. Brokers are ***kind of database***, used with celery because they are fast and efficient for a [Producer-Consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) scenario

**Why Not using SQL DB?**
SQL databases are capable of running in a network and dealing with concurrent access. The problem with them is that they are too slow. NoSQL databases, by contrast, are quite fast, but many times they lack reliability

I found one article, [**Celery: an overview of the architecture and how it works**](https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2017/celery-overview-archtecture-and-how-it-works/) on the internet, which explian everything in simple words